# What is the best way to check for a nil value in Lua?

Tags: if-statement, lua

I've started learning Lua and saw these two ways to check for `nil`:

```lua
local stats = game.ServerStorage.PlayerMoney:FindFirstChild(player.Name)

if (stats ~= nil) then 
    -- do stuff
end
    
if (stats) then 
    -- do stuff
end
```

Are the two `if` statements equivalent? If so, is there any advantage to including the extra `~= nil` part?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Statement "~= nil" works also if `stats = false`.

You can read in [docs](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.4.4):

> The condition expression of a control structure can return any value.
>   Both false and nil are considered false. All values different from nil
>   and false are considered true (in particular, the number 0 and the
>   empty string are also true).